# DynamoDB do not save data if user has saved data before with Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I'm working on a review app with DynamoDB & Lambda function and having an issue saving a review if user wrote a review before on the movie. This is how I save a review.

```js
const params = {
  TableName: 'movie_reviews',
  Item: {
    "movie_id":{
      S: MOVIE_ID
    },
    "review_id":{
      S: REVIEW_ID
    },
    "added_by": {
      S: USERNAME
    },
    "added_date": {
      S: ADDED_DATE
    },
    "rate": {
      N: INFLUENCER_RATE
    },
    "review": {
      S: REVIEW
    }
  }
};

dynamodb.putItem(params, function(err, data){
  if(err){
    console.log(err, err.stack);
    callback(null, err.stack);
  }else{
    console.log(data);
    callback(null);
  }
});
```

This works good to save a review but how do I make it work the way that if user(`added_by`) has a review under `movie_id` already then DO NOT save a review. So one user can only make one review on a movie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in nodejs you don't have to use the messy syntax like you did when defined the `Item` property.

Read about `aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient`.

---

Regarding your question, it is highly dependent on your table's modeling.

If I would want to permit many reviews on a movie, but at most one review from each user, I would set the partition key to be the movie ID and rowkey (sort key) to be the user ID, both form a unique item ID in the table.

This way, if a record is created (meaning there's a review on movie X from user Y) then you wouldn't be able to add another record as you'd receive some kind of Conflcit error, which means user Y has already left a review on movie X.

This would allow you to query efficiently all reviews per movie ID - which I assume is what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and the extra information! Very useful for me!

Comment: One more question, I implemented a solution from you and now it's updating the existing data rather than giving me an error. Do you have any idea make it not to update?

Comment: Read this page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html    > To prevent a new item from replacing an existing item, use a conditional expression that contains the attribute_not_exists function with the name of the attribute being used as the partition key for the table. Since every record must contain that attribute, the attribute_not_exists function will only succeed if no matching item exists.